How is it possible that a disk has 100% of active time but 0 KB/s of read speed and 0 KB/s of write speed?
I've noticed a disk that has 100% of active time but 0 KB/s of read speed and 0 KB/s of write speed according to Windows Task Manager:

How is it possible that a disk has 100% of active time but 0 KB/s of read speed and 0 KB/s of write speed?
I found https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-active-time-100-read-speed-0-kbs-write/39662b64-cd99-485f-9a9e-b57280c501b0 that mentions perhaps some program is thrashing the disk, but wouldn't thrashing cause the read speed or the write speed to be higher than 0 KB/s?

I wonder if this has to do with [the OS] to spin the disk down to save power/reduce noise.  I'm more familar with Linux, but I'm sure it can be done in Windows as well as its just a matter of issuing appropriate commands to the drive.  See, for example, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hdparm-command-in-linux-with-examples/
